# Реально ли использовать объявление всех функций через let / const / var?

Tags: javascript, code-style

Здравствуйте,

объявление функций через let / const / var - нужно ли к этому стремиться?

Если объявлять таким способом функции - приходится менять местами блоки, и получается не особо читаемо. Пример кода:

-как переобъявить ф-ции чтоб было красиво?

```js
// заменяет все <div class="include">html_link</div> на содержимое скачанное по ссылке html_link
function newInclude() {
    // собираем все инклуды
    const includes = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('include'));

    for (const include of includes) {
        const url = include.innerHTML;
        uploadUrl(include, url);
    }

    // скачиваем содержимое с url
    function uploadUrl(include, url) {
        fetch(url)
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.text();
            })
            .then(function(responseText) {
                insertInclude(include, responseText);
            });
    }
    // ставим содержимое url вместо блока include
    function insertInclude(include, responseText) {
        include.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', responseText);
        include.remove();
    }
}
```

```html
<div>some html...</div>

<div class="include">top/top.html</div>

<div>some html...</div>
```

Comment: Вы бы привели пример кода, в котором "все ломается".

Comment: функции обычно объявляются без let / const / var ))

Comment: @Igor , извините за мои объяснения. Я имел в виду "красивый понятный домик ломается", а код-то работает

Comment: Без примера кода действительно непонятно. Я могу написать ответ, но не уверен, что он будет адресовать проблему.

Comment: Стремится нужно к пониманию того зачем были введены let и const, а так же разницы между функциональным выражением и функции декларации и чтобы не писать вложенные функции.

Comment: @OlmerDale как можно это понимание получить?

Comment: об этом нужно читать, читать и ещё раз читать статьи, хотя бы с хабра. Но понимание все равно сразу не придет, нужно время и опыт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы имеет ввиду такого рода функции?

```
const r = function () {};
const b = () => {};
```

Такого рода функции называются функциональными выражением, его главным отличием от обычный функций в том, что интерпретатор обычный функции сразу же считывает, сохраняет в памяти, а потом по необходимости вызывает, но у таких функций глобальная видимость, тогда как у функциональные выражения нету глобальной видимости и считываются они только по ходу чтения кода интерпретатором. 
Т.е. они видимы только когда интерпретатор их прочитает.

На эту тему есть [статья в учебнике](http://learn.javascript.ru/function-declaration-expression), в котором все подробно рассказано.

Comment: Спасибо большое, но в чем собственно удобство этого? Вверху функции, внизу код не заврнутый в функции.. Или нужно по другому код оформлять? тогда как ?

Comment: В этом есть практический смысл, а не в оформлении кода.
Использование функционального выражения например позволяет создавать разные функции от определенных условий, но имя у функции будет одно.

Comment: Я еще нашел смысл - переименовать все анонимные функции. Правда если в функции есть this - получается проблема